# Worklight Application Center just keeps reloading

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, worklight-appcenter

I just installed Worklight 6.1 Application Center (running on WebSphere 8.5.5.1). When I load up the "Application Center" the page does a non-stop reloading/refreshing of the screen. I've tried Chrome and Internet Explorer.  Has anyone seen this and know what's causing it?

Comment: Is there anything in your logs? Did you use IBM Installation Manager to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so figured it out. Was strange. After the install I opened up the Worklight application center from the server and remotely. It went right into the web app without a login. On the top right it says "unknown user sign out", but I couldn't click on sign out.  I guess it somehow had me logged in after install but not really.  After awhile I guess it finally timed out maybe, because eventually I loaded it and was at a login prompt and on login it worked fine.

So if you have this problem, it's because you're not really logged in. Possibly restart the service or wait till it times out.

Or go to the /appcenterconsole/login.html directly to login.